# Adding and display array item in List View in Xamarin forms

Tags: arrays, listview, xamarin

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to add and display selected data in a list view, but unfortunately unable to display the data in a list view, if someone can help, thanks!
(here is my version of code)

```cs
namespace AppContacts
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
  SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection = DependencyService.Get().GetConnection();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
        ReadSelectedData();
    }

    public void ReadSelectedData()
    {
        int[] intArray;
        intArray = new int[4];
        intArray[0] = 175;
        intArray[1] = 197;
        intArray[1] = 757;
        intArray[3] = 915;

        var list = _connection.Table<Contacts>().ToListAsync().Result;
        var myAL = new ArrayList();
        foreach (int rowList in intArray)
        {
            var NewItem = list.Where(x => x.Contact_ID.Equals(rowList));
            myAL.Add(NewItem);
        }
     }
  }

}
```

Added Model class and XAML Page, XAML page name is ContentPage1

XAML Page
Page name is ContentPage1

```xml
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentPage1}, Path=BindingContext.myAL}" IsVisible="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Frame>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                    <Label Text="Hello World" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Contact_Address}" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Contact_eMail}" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Model Class

```cs
using SQLite
namespace AppContacts.Models
{
    public class Contacts
    {
        [PrimaryKey][AutoIncrement]
        public int Contact_ID { get; set; }
        public string Contact_Name { get; set; }
        public string Contact_Address {get; set; }        
        public string Contact_eMail { get; set; }
    }
}

[Output][1]


  [enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci5fK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppmp2.jpg
```

Comment: 1) don't use `Result` on async operations, learn to use async/await, 2) don't assign ItemsSource inside the loop, do it after the loop completes, 3) are you sure that `myAL` actually contains data?, 4) where is your XAML for the LIstView?

Comment: Hi, you need to check whether `list` contains data first, then could check  whether `NewItem` contains the matched data.

Comment: @Jason thank you for your prompt reply, already tried ItemSource after the loop, used async/await as well, myAL did contain the Data when checking with breaking points

Comment: Could be a problem with your XAML, but since you didn’t post that it’s hard to say

Comment: Hi @Junior_Jiang thank you for your reply, list did contain the data when checking it with breaking points, NewItem contains the matching Data as well!

Comment: @EmDe You could show the code of `Xaml` and  the model of listview cell, I will check that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, thank again, added XAML  and Model class, may that will help, appreciate your time and help.

Comment: if you are setting ItemsSource in code then remove it from the XAML.  Also try hardcoding a value to your Label to see if it displays.  You are not specifying any height values so it may not be rendering the layout correctly.

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, did tried as per your suggestions, formatted all labels to center displaying "Hello World" on first label, as I changed the text, but still not adding NewItem, either I am using  XAML page ItemSource or class code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with calling `ReadSelectedData` method in `OnAppearing()`, and set `ItemsSource` for **ListView**.

For example:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    int[] intArray;
    intArray = new int[4];
    intArray[0] = 175;
    intArray[1] = 197;
    intArray[2] = 757;
    intArray[3] = 915;

    var list = await _connection.Table<Contacts>().ToListAsync().Result;
    var myAL = new ArrayList();
    foreach (int rowList in intArray)
    {
        var NewItem = list.Where(x => x.Contact_ID.Equals(rowList));
        myAL.Add(NewItem);
    }
    listView.ItemSource = myAL;
}
```

=============================Update============================

I have checked the document about [Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__), you could see that the method return is not the `TSource` object.

> public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable Where >(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable source, Func<TSource,bool> >predicate);

It returns a `IEnumerable<TSource>` object, therefore your code:

```
var NewItem = list.Where(x => x.Contact_ID.Equals(rowList));
```

Should return a `IEnumerable<Contacts>` object.

Therefore, you could modify code as follows:

```
foreach (int rowList in intArray)
{
    var NewItem = list.Where(x => x.Contact_ID.Equals(rowList));
    myAL.Add(NewItem.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Using `NewItem.FirstOrDefault()` to get the `Contacts` object.

**Otherwise**, you could not use **Enumerable.Where Method** to do, also can use `foreach` to achieve that as follows:

```
foreach (int rowList in intArray)
{
    foreach (var newitem in list)
    {
        if(newitem.Contact_ID == rowList)
        {
            myAL.Add(newitem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Junior Jiang-MSFT, did tried it as you suggest, showing each array item when debagging with breaking points, but List View is still is blank!

Comment: @EmDe Could you show the string data of `myAL`, better with the screenshot of breakpoint?

Comment: Jian-MSFT, screen shot took by my mobile added, appreciate your help!

Comment: @EmDe Thanks for sharing the screenshot. It's strange, I could make it works in my local site. If you could share a sample projeck link here, it will be helpful to find where problem is.

Comment: Hi @Junior Jiang-MSFT, Thank you keep trying to helping me and asking the link to share, please give me a little time to create a new data file to share the link with you, thank you again for your help!

Comment: @EmDe Great! In addition, not using your real data ,you only need to use the sample data to reproduce the project.

Comment: Hi @Junior Jiang-MSFT, Please send me your email to share the link of sample project with you, thank you!

Comment: @EmDe Sorry, I can not provide emial accout here, but you could upload it in **OneDrice** or **Github**, and it's free and convenient.

Comment: Jiang-MSFT, Thank you for a good suggestion, here is the link for GitHub,  https://github.com/EmDe-NJ/AppContacts, hope you will find a way to display array items in the List View.

Comment: @EmDe Thanks for sharing the link. However, it has been invalid. You could update the link here, and I will check in local site.

Comment: @Jiang-MSFT, I didn't know that it was not public, I change the status to public, hope it will work, sorry for inconvenience. If there is a problem again, please help me to upload on GitHub, this is my first ever

Comment: @EmDe Hi, now I could have seen the proect. Before downloading to check, I found that there is a `.db` file inside it. I want to know whether the data is actual data? I can not use your actual data to test, and not suggest that upload actual data in Github.

Comment: @EmDe Hi, I haven't downloaded your project to test. But I have found the reason, you could have a try with the method from my updated anwer.

Comment: @EmDe I haven't tested code, if works let me know that.

Comment: Hi @Junior Jiang-MSFT, Sorry couldn't check your comments, FYI data is not actual, that is why took time to create it, thank you for your time to take interest to help me, I didn't check your suggested option yet, I will check it ASAP and will let you know!

Comment: Hi Junior Jiang-MSFT, THANK YOU!, it works, I really appreciate the time and concern you showed to solve my problem, it means a lot to me, Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Junior Jiang-MSFT, checked the second method as well, both works fine, Thank you you again, you are awesome :).

Comment: Jiang-MSFT, a question related to same App and similar procedure , do I need to create a new question page or I can ask here?

Comment: @EmDe Yes, you'd better create a new question in SO. And about this question, if the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Jiang-MSFT, Thank you, answer is useful I did click the mark 

Comment: Hi @Junior Jiang-MSFT, you didn't check my other question, I posted on yesterday, if not too busy, please take a look, Thanks!

Comment: @EmDe Okey, you could share the other question link here, I will check that.

Comment: Jiang-MSFT, here is the link, I appreciate the time and effort  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566213/in-case-of-multiple-array-lists-can-i-store-them-somewhere-and-call-them-or-ne

Comment: @EmDe Thanks, I will check that. If good ideas will update there.

Comment: @EmDe My colleague has answered that for you, you could have a look at that.