# In case of Multiple Array Lists, can I store them somewhere and call them, or need to create separate class for each AL

Tags: xamarin, arraylist, xamarin.forms

In my application I have multiple Array lists, (more than 20 in my case), trying to find a way to store them somewhere and call them back if possible. Like old ways in Modules in VB. Here is my code!

### Models Class Code

public class Contacts

```
public class Contacts
{
    [PrimaryKey][AutoIncrement]
    public int Contact_ID { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Name { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Address { get; set; }
    public string Contact_eMail { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Main Page

```
`public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection 
        = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // I have more than 20 This type of Array Lists, and some contains 
        more than 30 items 
        
        int[] intArray;
        intArray = new int[4];
        intArray[0] = 13;
        intArray[1] = 14;
        intArray[2] = 18;
        intArray[3] = 21;

        var list = _connection.Table<Contacts>().ToListAsync().Result;
        var myAL = new ArrayList();
        foreach (int rowList in intArray)
        {
            var NewItem = list.Where(x => x.Contact_ID.Equals(rowList));
            myAL.Add(NewItem.FirstOrDefault());
        }

        listView.ItemsSource = myAL;
    }
}`
```

---

### XAML Page

```
`<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="True"  IsVisible="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightYellow">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding Contact_Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Contact_Address}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Contact_eMail}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>`
```

---

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvMbd.png)

Comment: You could convert your ArrayLists to a json string,then save and get it with [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) by key-value.

Comment: Thank you @Leo Zhu - MSFT for your response, I will check it out, will let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple sample :

create class for the arraylists **MyArrayData** (for example there are two list here):

```
public class MyArrayData
{
   public IList<string> StringArray { get; set; }
   public IList<int> IntArray { get; set; }
}
```

then you could save it like:

```
MyArrayData dataArray = new MyArrayData() { IntArray = new List<int>() { 1,2, 3, 4 }, StringArray = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" } };
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataArray);
Preferences.Set("list", jsonString);
```

get it like with the key:

```
string dateJason = Preferences.Get("list", "");
MyArrayData myArrayData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyArrayData>(dateJason);
var intArray = myArrayData.IntArray;
var stringArray = myArrayData.StringArray;
```

Comment: Thank you @Leo Zhu - MSFT, for the detail answer, I will check it out and will let you know!

Comment: appreciate your valuable time, but this saving part is not working, upload screen shot may that help, thanks!

Comment: @EmDe Hi, you need to use `using Xamarin.Essentials;` in your project, then can use `Preferences`. And you'd better share the screen shot in your question, then other people will see that conveniently.

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, thank you for correcting me for the screen shot, remeved from answering side and added at question side after using Xamarin Preferences causing the error!

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, It is working, my question is there, how to call/select them like Select case in VB, suggest me if need to ask a separate question to get the answer please, Thanks a lot for making this work for me! (and how to vote you guys)

Comment: @EmDe Yes, you could ask a new question in SO.

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, I need your help again if you have time, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830455/a-single-label-can-display-2-data-fields-alternately-select-by-user , Thank you!

Comment: @EmDe Okey, I will check that, if good ideas will update there.

Comment: Hello @JuniorJiang-MSFT, posted again my same question, couldn't get the answer working, if you can help please!          
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911936/how-a-user-select-to-display-1-out-of-two-or-more-fields-on-a-single-label-in