# A Single Label can display 2 Data fields alternately select by user

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, label, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to use a single Label to display one of the two data fields alternately in Xamarin Forms. Only Label 1 Display the binding field and second Label which I am trying to use a variable "DisplayField" is not displaying either 'Contact_Address' or 'Contact_eMail'

Model class

```
public class Contacts
{
    [PrimaryKey][Autoincrement]
    public int Contact_ID { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Name { get; set; }
    public string Contact_Address { get; set; }
    public string Contact_eMail { get; set; }
    public string DisplayField { get; set; }
}
```

XAML page

```
  <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Display Address" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill" Clicked="Display_Address" />
        <Button Text="Display Email" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill" Clicked="Display_eMail" />
        <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding DisplayField}" />
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                            <Frame >
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Contact_Name}" FontSize="Medium" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding DisplayField}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class FieldSwap : ContentPage
{
    readonly FieldViewModel _fieldViewModel;
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
    public ObservableCollection<Contacts> CList { get; set; }
    public static string DisplayField { get; private set; }

    public static int caseSwitch { get; private set; }

    public FieldSwap()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _fieldViewModel = new FieldViewModel();
        _fieldViewModel.Field = "Contact_Address";
        
        this.BindingContext = _fieldViewModel;
    }

    public static void SelectField()
    {
        

        switch (caseSwitch)
        {
            case 1:
                DisplayField = "Contact_Address";
                break;

            case 2:
                DisplayField = "Contact_eMail";
                break;

            default:
                DisplayField = ("Contact_Address");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Display_Address(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        caseSwitch = 1;
        SelectField();
        ReadData();
    }

    private void Display_eMail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        caseSwitch = 2;
        SelectField();
        ReadData();
    }

    public void ReadData()
    {
        var list = _connection.Table<Contacts>().ToListAsync().Result;
        CList = new ObservableCollection<Contacts>(list);
        listView.ItemsSource = CList;
    }
}
```

View model class

```
public class FieldViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    String _field;

    public string Field
    {
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_field, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                _field = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DisplayField");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _field;
        }
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
        PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TaUh.png)
[Screen Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7vpi.png)

Comment: `DisplayField` is not a property of class `Contacts`

Comment: @Jason, I tried, but doesn't work, and I didn't get that either that why I need it there

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT, thank you again for spending time to help me out, but list labels are not displaying anything, except picker which giving option and it changing by clicking, added screen shot of "ProprtyChanged" warning, may this causes the error

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT, I am sure it will, keep trying with it, added a screen shot while selectedm is true, but listView1 is still blank, thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display different value in ListView by user selected, I suggest you can use Picker to choose, I do one sample that you can take a look.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Picker x:Name="choose" SelectedIndexChanged="choose_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Contact_Address</x:String>
                    <x:String>Contact_eMail</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </Picker>
        <ListView
            x:Name="listview1"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label
                                FontSize="Medium"
                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                Text="{Binding Contact_Name}" />
                            <Label
                                IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference root}, Path=BindingContext.selectedm}"
                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                Text="{Binding Contact_eMail}" />
                            <Label
                                IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference root}, Path=BindingContext.selecteda}"
                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                Text="{Binding Contact_Address}" />
                        </StackLayout>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

 public partial class Page31 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Contacts> items { get; set; }
    private Boolean _selecteda;
    public Boolean selecteda
    {
        get { return _selecteda; }
        set
        {
            _selecteda = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selecteda");
        }
    }
    private Boolean _selectedm;
    public Boolean selectedm
    {
        get { return _selectedm; }
        set
        {
            _selectedm = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selectedm");
        }
    }
    public Page31()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        items = new ObservableCollection<Contacts>();

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            Contacts contact = new Contacts()
            {
                Contact_ID = i, Contact_Name = "cherry " + i, Contact_Address = "the street " + i, Contact_eMail = "cherry@outlook.com "+i
            };
            items.Add(contact);
        }
       
        this.BindingContext = this;
       
    }
  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;   
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void choose_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

        if (selectedIndex ==0)
        {
            selecteda = true;
            selectedm = false;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedm = true;
            selecteda = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your input, so far only displaying picker options, trying to modify it, I will let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: thank you again for spending time to help me out, but list labels are not displaying anything, except picker which giving option and it changing by clicking, added screen shot of "ProprtyChanged" warning, may this causes the error

Comment: @EmDe Yes, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify data changed, if you want to display data when page open, you just set selecteda or selectedm as true in page constructor. So my answer can not resolve your problem?